# unreliable npm installs in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am running npm within a `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM node:9.11-alpine
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install && npm run build
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "watch"]
```

When I do `docker build .` I have a low chance of the build completing successfully. Over a period of a few minutes if I periodically run the same command without any changes to my `Dockerfile` or anything else, the build will succeed. Most times though I get this;

```
...
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-5b126a50/js/browser/bluebird.js'
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/json-bigint/-/json-bigint-0.2.3.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-26T08_18_44_426Z-debug.log
```

Because the build fails, I cannot check `/root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-26T08_18_44_426Z-debug.log` (at least to my knowledge). The error says its a connectivity issue but does the online npm repository have some sort of throttling? Or is docker acting like a proxy?

Is there a way of using npm with docker which avoids this error that I am not aware of?

**EDIT**

The verbose logs from running `npm install` manually within the container using shell

```
1420 verbose type system
1421 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.10.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
1421 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
1421 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:180:13)
1421 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:395:9)
1421 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
1421 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
1421 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
1422 verbose cwd /usr/src/app
1423 verbose Linux 4.14.48-2-MANJARO
1424 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
1425 verbose node v9.11.2
1426 verbose npm  v5.6.0
1427 error code ENOTFOUND
1428 error errno ENOTFOUND
1429 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.10.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
1430 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
1430 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
1430 error network
1430 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
1430 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
1431 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Do you get the same results running this outside a container?

Comment: The problem may be due to the copy line if it copy the `node_modules/` directory. have you tried without that?

Comment: @jannis I haven't tried I don't have node installed on my host machine

Comment: Then do it and see if this is a Docker-specific problem or a problem with your host machine's network configuration/instability.

Answer (score 3):

So the connection issue was indeed a local connection issue. I used a different wifi from a different location I have confirmed it is the wifi settings of the appartment I am in. Since it was my first time using npm and docker together, I couldn't rule out other issues...

As for logging, I have discovered two great docker options for finding logs even when a container fails to build;

```
docker logs <containerid>
```

and

```
docker cp <containerid>:/path/to/log.file ./local/path/of/log.file
```

which work on containers that aren't running. This has allowed me to debug issues much more efficiently without changing the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't separate `docker build` without entrypoint and `docker run` with the entrypoint?

Try:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:9.11-alpine
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install && npm run build
```

After that, create the image:

```
docker build -t your_image_name .
```

Run your command with network mode = host to avoid some problems related to network:

```
docker run -d --net=host your_image_name npm run watch
```

If it doesn't work, you can check your log in two ways:

1. Launch container sharing a volume: `docker run -d -v /tmp/any_dir:/root/.npm/_logs/ ...`: avalilable from the host.
2. Launch container with sh, get into the container, execute command manually and check logfile: `docker run -ti your_image_name sh`

Comment: The error happens at `RUN npm install` and still happens when I use `docker build --net="host" .`

Comment: Just add another step. Remove `npm install && npm run build` from Dockerfile, create image, run container with `sh` and see logs after checking internet connection inside docker.

Comment: I don't understand, if I remove the problem line, then surely there won't be any logs to check?

Comment: Execute your npm install etc inside container shell